# QUdpSocket HeartBeat behaviour

Tags: qt, qudpsocket

I need to send the status of my Qt application through and Upd socket every seconds. How can I achive this? Should I subclass QThread e using QThread::sleep or is there a best approch ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I use a different approch:

a `QTimer`:

```
QTimer iAmAliveTimer.setInterval(1500);
iAmAliveTimer.setSingleShot(true);
connect(&iAmAliveTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendIamAlive()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
iAmAliveTimer.start();
```

when the `SLOT` is called, I send what I need through my socket.